# Why doesn't app expose /health-check-path endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I just created my first `Consul` aware Spring Boot application but it doesn't work correctly.

The app is pretty simple:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }

}

spring:
      application:
        name: exmpl
      cloud:
        consul:
          discovery:
            health-check-path: /my-health-check
            health-check-interval: 20s
            tags: exmplTag


dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-consul', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
}
```

I would like the mention that the app is discovered correctly and properties are picked up correctly. As you can see on the screenshot the tag "exmplTag" is displayed correctly.

[image]

Despite of it, the `health-check-path` isn't exposed and `Consul` unable to health check it.

Does it mean that I have to create the endpoint on my own or do I have an incorrect config?

Answer (score 0):

per default without setting the health check endpoint consul will use the default spring actuator `/health` endpoint.

So you need to add a dependency on spring actuators.

If you set a custom health check url, you need to provide that url (`/my-health-check`).

[registering with consul](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/2.2.0.M1/#_registering_with_consul)

Comment: AFAIK actuator is exposed on a management port that can differ from server port, meanwhile Consul polls endpoint on a server port. Do you mean that Consul is intended to poll actuator’s endpoint?